# running ec2config.exe -sysprep remotely using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I am working through a process for creating an AMI from instance, for that i need to run sysprep before shutting down the machine and then create an AMI from it.

trouble is whatever i do using powershell, it wont execute sysprep.

this is what my invoke-comment looks like right now

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $newAdminPassword -AsPlainText -force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(".\Administrator",$securePassword)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostName -ScriptBlock { Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Ec2Config.exe" -ArgumentList '-sysprep' -NoNewWindow -PassThru  -Verbose -R} -Credential $credential
```

it doesnt run this command, simply prints out this output

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                    PSComputerName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                    --------------
      7       1      252        108     3     0.00   2556 Ec2Config                      10.1.7.254
```

any idea what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that output suggests that it IS running that command. The `-Passthru` parameter of `Start-Process` pipes the `Process` object to the pipeline, and it won't wait for the process to terminate.

I guess the problem is that you want the command to wait while the process completes so you can do the next job, viz restart the computer and image it. If you want to wait for the process to complete you might find it easier to just use `invoke-expression` or just the `&` operator to run the `Ec2Config.exe` command.